Estimating noise power from sensor signal
I'm a beginner in signal processing and a bit lost. I have sensor readings from a load sensor of real system. I want to replicate the noise inherent in the signal in simulink using the Bandlimited White Noise Block. If I assume the noise to be additive white gaussian noise, how would I obtain the noise power parameter.
I have tried filtering out the noise from the sensor measurements to obtain the PSD from the auto-correlation, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.
Used this post as an initial reference.
Noise Characterization
Any recommendations would be of massive help!
Thanks!

If you mean you have tried filtering out the noise from sensor measurements to obtain the PSD, then please edit your question with this clarification.  It's a minor nit, but people find all kinds of strange ways to try to find stuff out.

Sorry for the confusion, but yes I tried filtering out the noise from sensor measurements.

This isn't the best way to do this for any given system, but it's pretty good for most systems, and probably best at your level of understanding:

Set up your measurement apparatus with a known-constant input.  Choosing a value of zero will make the signal processing easiest; choosing a value centered around the expected measurements you want to take will be a best fit if you suspect your apparatus to change characteristics with loading.
Measure the longest sample vector that you can.
Plot the result in its raw form and see if it looks sensible to you.
Detrend*, window**, and calculate the PSD.
Plot the resulting PSD and see if it looks sensible to you.


* If you're using a pre-packaged PSD calculator, it may detrend anyway.  If not -- it fits your data to a straight line in time ($a t + b$) and subtracts it out.  Since most collected data has an offset and a trend, and since in this case that's exactly what you don't want clogging up the underlying FFT -- detrend.
** Again, this may be included in a pre-packaged PSD calculator.  If not -- sampling a vector of data out of an infinitely long sample is, inherently, making an approximation of the process.  The window suppresses end-effects and for the purposes of getting the power spectral density, it makes the approximation better.
